# How can I set CMYK values in Scribus?

Tags: cmyk, color-spaces, scribus

When I create a new CMYK color for my document, the color’s values change when I edit it back, as you can see in this [animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp7dm.gif) (sorry for the bad quality):

[image]

For example:

```
65,00% becomes 65,10%
40,00%   ->    40,00%
30,00%   ->    30,20%
5,00%    ->    5,10%
```

How can I solve this and have the right value applied?

Comment: What version of Scribus please? 1.4.x or 1.5.x series is important for all Scribus related questions. Precise version is even more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found a bug report, similar to your (and also mine) issue: http://bugs.scribus.net/view.php?id=10054

Not checked if it works, but you can check that possible workaround:

```
Just found a workaround:
- Set the color value: 90.2% (90,2% in my german version)
- Change some other color either via up/down or the color scrollcontrol and change it back.
- Close the dialog.
- Reopen the dialog - color is ok.
```